# Javascript redirect - remove parent location

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am using a javascript form script and I want to redirect to an external website. I set the redirect to www.paypal.me but it actually redirects the user to www.mysite.com/www.paypal.me

How can I edit the code below to instead redirect the user to the actual site, not prefaced by my own URL?

```
var redirect = "www.paypal.me";
...
this.submitOK = function(){
    if( redirect == '' ){
        showThankYouMessage();
        return;
    };

    try{
        if( parent ) parent.location.href = redirect;
    }catch(e){
        location.href = redirect;
    };
}
}
```

Comment: give it a protocol "//www.paypal.me"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a small overview over the redirect methods in js: https://appendto.com/2016/04/javascript-redirect-how-to-redirect-a-web-page-with-javascript/

To a redirect use something like this:

```
<script>
    var locationn = "https://google.com";
    window.location = locationn;
```